# What is the semantics of block labels in `eth_getNewFilter`?

Tags: rpc, filters

I am wondering how exactly `fromBlock` and `toBlock` in `eth_getNewFilter` are supposed to work. The documentation is a little confusing.

1. [This page](https://ethereum.github.io/execution-apis/api-documentation/) (which seems to be official) says that these parameters only accept (hex-encoded) numerical values, and not string labels like `"latest"`. But all the major provider docs and [this page](https://ethereum.org/developers/docs/apis/json-rpc#eth_newfilter) (also official?) says that the labels are also accepted.
2. What is the meaning of `toBlock="latest"`? Does it mean that the filter is "open-ended", and will return log entries as new transactions are coming through?
3. What is the meaning of `fromBlock="latest"`? Is it equivalent to setting `fromBlock` to whatever the block number was at the moment of the creation of the filter?
4. [The aforementioned official page](https://ethereum.org/developers/docs/apis/json-rpc#eth_newfilter) says

   > or "pending", "earliest" for not yet mined transactions.

   How is "earliest" the same as "pending"? Shouldn't "earliest" evaluate to 0 or whatever the genesis block number was?
5. How is "pending" supposed to work for these parameters seeing as how you can't get receipts of pending transactions, so they are not really executed yet?